# Visual Studio 2015 RC :: Keyboard shortcut "commit current file"

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Release Candidate (RC) on Windows 10 Build 10130.

I would like to create a Visual Studio 2015 keyboard shortcut to "commit current file" in the Code Editor window, **or** when I have selected one or more files in the Solution Explorer window.

How is this possible?

Comment: Not an answer but also take note of keyboard shortcuts for `Team.Git.GoToGitActiveRepositiories`, `Team.Git.GoToGitChanges`, `Team.Git.GoToGitSynchronixation` as potential targets for the keyboard. I mapped them to ctrl-shift-G, ctrl-shift-... C + R + S.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow these directions in the Visual Studio environment:

1. Open **Tools --> Options**
2. Navigate to **Environment --> Keyboard**
3. Type "commit" into the Show commands containing
4. Select the `Team.Git.Commit` Visual Studio command
5. Under *Use new shortcut in*, select `Text Editor`
6. Under *Press shortcut keys*, type a shortcut (eg. <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + C</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + C</kbd>)

Repeat the above steps, but substitute `Solution Explorer` for Step #5. Use the same keyboard shortcut for consistency.

### Result

- When you press the keyboard shortcut in the `Text Editor` window, you will commit the currently opened file in the editor.
- When you press the keyboard shortcut in the `Solution Explorer` window, you will commit any changed / added files that are selected in the `Solution Explorer`.

[image]

Comment: Works. :) You seem to need to close / reopen any text editor window you want to use that in, ditto for VS itself and the Solution Explorer. When in doubt, turn it off and back on again.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It does activate the Team Explorer window, but doesn't actually create the commit.

Comment: It's not solution explorer, it's Team Explorer window,Tested in vs2019